# Archiving or Exporting SMS Group Messages

Tags: sms

How do you export/archive SMS messages received from a group?
Are they stored in some other database separate from all other SMS messages?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7, and the stock SMS app.

I have several (all the free ones) SMS archival apps, and I notice that messages that I received because they were sent to a group are never included in these archives.

This became most obvious when I received 200+ messages of a conversation between two people, and I was part of that group. I wanted to archive the conversation and it only shows up as 3 messages. Only the ones sent explicitly to me, not any of the other 200 messages.

These messages appear just like all other messages. There is no way for me to distinguish the fact that they were sent to a group and not just myself (except for being told that they weren't texting me in error... I was part of the group).

**EDIT**

After working on this for some time. I have noticed that the messages to the group are MMS (multimedia messages).

This likely changes the focus of the question.
Is there any way to export the text of a multimedia message?

Comment: I don't think you _can_ distinguish that. There is no concept of "groups" for SMS messages if I'm not mistaken. Messages sent to multiple recipients are sent as one SMS per recipient.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would have thought the same, but I have found no way to export these texts. All my other texts export normally. Texts that I perceive to be "to the group" are not exported.